# What formula would you use to solve this problem?

Tags: calculus

> The radius of a ripple in an ocean, which always remains circular, expands at a rate of 6 in/min. When the radius is 18 inches away from the center, what is the rate of change of the area covered by this ripple with respect to time?

The answer is $216\pi$ in/min but I'm not sure what formula to use. I tried differentiating $A = πr^2$ and plugging in $r = 6$ but I'm still not getting the right answer.

Comment: $A = \pi r^2$ implies that $\mathrm{d} A / \mathrm{d}r = 2\pi r$.  In these kinds of problems, we treat the differentials $\mathrm{d} A$ and $\mathrm{d}r$ as variables representing, respectively, the rate at which the area is changing, and the rate at which the radius is changing.  Substitute the appropriate values (hint: what does $6$ in/min represent in this setting?) and work from there.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show more of your work. Hint/question. Are you differentiating with respect to _time_, not $g$?

Comment: Something is missing in your question. Rate of change of the area must be measured in square inches per minute

Comment: What is the area after time $t$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson But if I substitute 6 into dA/dr = 2πr, I get 12π, which doesn't match the answer.

Comment: @brainkid What does $6$ in/min represent in terms of the variables which are present in the problem?  Remember that $r$ and $A$ are not the only variables; as per my previous comment, the differentials are variables, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given ${dr \over dt}=6$ and $ r=18$ . now
$${dA \over dt}={d \over dt}(\pi r^2)=2\pi r{dr \over dt}=2.\pi.18.6=216\pi$$

Comment: Thank you for the direct and thorough response! :)